# How to compile Gnucap?

Tags: make, compiler, gnu

I installed GCompris today on my Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS PC for my little brother. He wants to test out the electric circuit game, but it requires `gnucap` to be installed.

So, I found the source code of `gnucap` on its document website on a `.tar.gz` archive and I downloaded it. I extracted the files and I opened the `INSTALL` instructions file. I tried to compile the package, but `make` runs into an error (`Error [2]` to be exact). (I'll post a screen shot later.)

Can anyone help me on compiling the package? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Bajiru

Comment: Do you really need to compile it? it appears to be available from the `universe` repository: [Package: gnucap (1:0.36~20091207-2) \[universe\]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnucap)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the link, but GCompris requires Gnucap to be installed in '/usr/bin/gnucap'. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: If you look at the package's [list of files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/gnucap/filelist) you should see that it **does** install as `/usr/bin/gnucap`. If you're still having issues with `GCompris` then please start a separate question about that.

Comment: @steeldriver OK, I'll try and tell you! Thanks!

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the 1st comment! Now GCompris' circuit game works perfectly! I really appreciate your help!